# Why is variable index ANDed twice with 0x1f?

Tags: java, scala, hashmap, immutability, trie

I was reading about the underlying data structures for immutable collections in Scala (`HashMap` and `Vector`, more precisely) and while reading the code, I came across the [`get0`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.scala#L308) function in `HashTrieMap`.

Why is the variable `index` AND-ed with `0x1f` again in line 312? It seems to me that the result is the same (i.e. the second AND is not necessary). What am I missing?

Here is the aforementioned function:

```
override def get0(key: A, hash: Int, level: Int): Option[B] = {
  val index = (hash >>> level) & 0x1f // index is AND-ed with 0x1f
  val mask = (1 << index)
  if (bitmap == - 1) {
    elems(index & 0x1f).get0(key, hash, level + 5) // once again, AND-ed with 0x1f
  } else if ((bitmap & mask) != 0) {
    val offset = Integer.bitCount(bitmap & (mask-1))
    elems(offset).get0(key, hash, level + 5)
  } else
    None
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not missing anything. Indeed the second AND is not necessary.

Comment: Because people aren't perfect? Perhaps submit a PR to remove it.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Sure :) But it's kind of natural to assume the guys who wrote that code are insanely good (which they are) and there is an obscure and deeper reason why it must be done *that* way precisely. It wasn't my intention to be pedantic about it.

Comment: If there is a subtle reason, at least leaving it uncommented was surely a mistake.

Comment: @ale64bit People can be very good and still make mistakes ;-)